# How to create invisible item in Beamer Overlays case by case?

Tags: beamer, pdftex, overlays, transparency

Please allow me to explain my situation. I am using Beamer overlay for a quiz. (And I love the pdf output). So, I give the students multiple choices on first slide. And next slide they get the answer. But, I want to add an additional comment after the answer, to describe little more about the topic.  Here is what I have.

```
\begin{frame}{Programming Basics}
\texttt{Comments are followed by \underline{\hspace{2cm}}}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item<1> !
    \item<1> @
    \item<1> ::
    \item<1-2> ;
    \item<2> Only show this in second slide, ; I am comment
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
```

I like `\setbeamercovered{transparent}` so I don’t want to set to `invisible`. I just want the last item to show up after the answer, without a grey transparent item showing up on first slide, because this can give them a hint!!! (See the attached image)[image]

I did some research but could not find the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`\invisible` is your new friend

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Programming Basics}
    \texttt{Comments are followed by \underline{\hspace{2cm}}}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item<1> !
        \item<1> @
        \item<1> ::
        \item<1-2> ;
        \invisible<1>{\item Only show this in second slide, ; I am comment}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is `almost` exactly what I want. Thank you. Is there a way to remove a numbering in it. (item 5th)

Comment: Put it outside the `itemize`-environment or inside the 4th item (maybe with a new line)?

Comment: A newline works but, what if my answer is item 1 or 2, it messes up the formatting.

Comment: @Cricrazy Where do you want your comment to be if 1 is the answer? After item 1 or at the end?

Comment: Sam, I got it working. I wanted it to be outside the `itemize` at the end.  here is what I did. `\vspace{10mm}
  \textbf{\invisible<1>{Semi-colon is used for commenting}}}` Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Cricrazy You are welcome!