# Beamer nested Itemize

Tags: beamer, itemize, presentations

currently I'm doing my first lecture with latex and beamer.

I have problems with using a nested itemize. On the first slide, everything should be visible respectively transparent. BUT: The nested itemize is fully invisible. If the slide with the upper point gets full visible, the nested itemize items get transparent. But I want to have them invisible the whole frame.

A example:

```
\begin{itemize}
\item<1-> First
    \begin{itemize}
        \item<2-> Sub-Itemize
        \item<3-> Sub-Itemize
    \end{itemize}
\item<4-> Second
    \begin{itemize}
        \item<5-> Again Sub-Itemize
        \item<6-> Again Sub-Itemize
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
```

This is what I have:

[image: This is what I have]

This is what I want:

[image: This is what I want]

Comment: Can you make a compilable MWE? And please make clear which elements you want to display on which slides. On the first slide should the things be visible or transparent (this is confusing).

Comment: Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/306290/124842 or http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/53861/124842 help you?

Comment: Sorry, how can i post longer comments with code? It isn't possible to answer with a lot of characters. :-(

Comment: I edited with prepared Screenshots. See my pics

Answer (score 4):

The second itemization is visible, just fainter then the first. You can adjust the opaqueness or use another transparency effect, see `17.6 Transparency Effects` in the beamer user guide.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamercovered{transparent=50}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item<1-> First
    \begin{itemize}
        \item<2-> Sub-Itemize
        \item<3-> Sub-Itemize
    \end{itemize}
\item<4-> Second
    \begin{itemize}
        \item<5-> Again Sub-Itemize
        \item<6-> Again Sub-Itemize
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]